# open menu link (PDF) in new tab not download

Tags: menus, pdf

I have a specific requirements where the menu item has link to the PDF. My needs are to open the PDF on the click of the menu item in new window.

I have checked the option of open link in new tab in wordpress menu system but the issue is in the new page the PDF dont gets opened and instead get downloaded.

Please help and advice.

Thanks in Advance
ST

Comment: Isn't this because you browser needs to have an installed extension to actually be able to read PDF files?

Comment: This is also something that can be over-ridden by user controlled settings in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. It sounds like your setup is correct, so it may be your own settings are determining the outcome.